# Flutter incDecFactor of 0.05 for all items in specific product category

Tags: flutter

How can I make the incDecFactor 0.05 only for the products that are in 1 specific product category?

Comment: nobody knows what `incDecFactor` is

Comment: I am following this installation tutorial. https://pub.dev/packages/number_inc_dec

Comment: so, write it in your question - otherwise nobody will help you in any way